# Creating CGColor from RGB Value

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift3, nscolor

I use the following code to set the background of a viewcontroller

```
    view.wantsLayer = true
    let myColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 50, green: 50, blue: 50, alpha: 1.0)
    view.layer?.backgroundColor = myColor.cgColor
```

But on debugging `myColor` i get the following color instead of the intended color

[image]

Comment: @techno You need to 255 instead of 256 even though it's only a fractional difference mine was the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/1526323-colorwithcalibratedred?language=objc). Anything above 1 is considered as 1. You need to divide each value by 255.

```swift
view.wantsLayer = true
let myColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 50/255, green: 50/255, blue: 50/255, alpha: 1.0)
view.layer?.backgroundColor = myColor.cgColor
```

Also, check this out -> [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5102757/7098650)

Answer (score 0):

Range of color components (RGBA) vary between [0,1]

[`init(red:green:blue:alpha:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/1535804-init)

> Creates a color object with the specified red, green, blue, and alpha
>   channel values. This method accepts extended color component values.
>   If the red, green, blue, or alpha values are outside of the 0-1.0
>   range,

So you can get `cgColor`

```
view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 50.0/255.0, green: 50.0/255.0, blue: 50.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

Comment: I seem to bump into you every time. So, Is it 256 or 255?